# lifelines.CoxPHFitter - how are the p-values calculated?

Tags: regression, survival, p-value, cox-model, lifelines

I assume that lifelines.CoxPHFitter is using a Likelihood-ratio test (or is it using Wald?) to calculate p-values when testing for significance. But I have to be sure: is there an official source where I can find what test are used? (I was not successful searching threw the documentation of lifelines)
Is lifelines.CoxPHFitter using the same test while performing a univariate and multivariate Cox Regression?

Answer (score 0):

Software-specific questions are off-topic on this site, but there's nothing to indicate that `lifelines` goes beyond usual practice for Cox models in this respect. The usual practice with Cox models is to restrict the likelihood ratio test to the entire model and report Wald tests for individual coefficients. Those values come directly from the final model fit. An example on [this page](https://lifelines.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Survival%20Regression.html)* shows that the coefficient 95% CI reported by `lifelines` are symmetric about the point estimate in the original coefficient (log-hazard) scale, which is what Wald estimates provide.

It's possible to calculate profile likelihoods to get confidence intervals and associated p-values for individual coefficients, but that requires refitting the entire model over a range of potential values for each coefficient in question. See, for example, Section 3.4.1 of [Therneau and Grambsch](https://www.springer.com/us/book/9780387987842). In the original coefficient scale, unlike the necessarily symmetric Wald CI, with small samples the profile-likelihood confidence intervals can be asymmetric about the point estimate.

---

Other Cox regression software also reports Wald and score tests on the entire model, not evident in the linked `lifelines` example.